# Displaying text box input to a label?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm having a problem with making a button display the input in a textbox to a label. This is how it looks like.

[image]

Now forget about the radio buttons and the check boxes. I want what the user types inside the text box with the placeholder "Name:" to display to the label that's to the right of the button.

```
//                  Name TextBox
    //***********************************************************
    //Enter your name textbox
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    //Empties the textbox once it's focused
    private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
        if(textBox1.Focus())
            textBox1.Text = String.Empty;
    }
    //Resets the placeholder text for password textbox
    private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!textBox1.Focused)
            textBox1.Text = "Name: ";
    }
    //***********************************************************

    //                  Password TextBox
    //***********************************************************
    //Enter your password textbox
    private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    //Empties the password  textbox once it's focused
    private void textBox2_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(textBox2.Focus())
            textBox2.Text = String.Empty;
    }
    //Resets the placeholder text for password textbox
    private void textBox2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!textBox2.Focused)
            textBox2.Text = "Password: ";
    }
    //***********************************************************


    //Display Name button
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label5.Text = textBox1.Text;
    }
    //Display password button
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label6.Text = textBox2.Text;
    }
```

1) Just to clarify: I've made the initial text inside the text boxes a placeholder. And the placeholder text will reappear inside the text box once it loses focus. I've used both focus() method and focused property because I simply do not know the difference. 
(I don't know if I should ask about the difference between the two in another question, so please let me know)

2) Now when I input whateva into the text box, then press the display button, the default placeholder text reappears and the input do not appear in the label. Naturally, I also don't want the placeholder text to ever appear at the label.

Obviously I'm new at Windows Forms and worse, I find it hard to articulate my questions when writing WinForms applications. So if any code is missing from my question, let me know.

Comment: This looks like a homework question. So, **hint hint** `textBoxX_Leave` happens before `buttonX_Click`

Comment: @GrantWinney Actually I'm very annoyed with how they are named :). I tried changing the name in the properties but the change did not happen in the method names. Everything else like referring to the button in the code did change but the method names did not change.

Comment: Now the for the difference between focus() method and focused property. Should I ask that in another question?

Comment: Focused is like a question, it's a boolean. So if you want to know if a control has focus, do this: `if(textBox1.Focused) { MessageBox.Show("This textbox has focus"); }` and if you want to force the `TextBox` to gain focus, then use `textBox1.Focus();`

Comment: @Aeron Great. But what do I do with bool return value from the method?. So for example, in this program, can I use the Focus() to focus on the textBox1 upon program load (I did it in this one by assigning ActiveControl to the textBox1 in the Form1_load method)

Comment: You can do that. I would recommend assigning focus to any control from within the Form1_Shown event though, not Form1_Load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change the check, if user has made any changes then you won't reappear the placeholder:

```
//Resets the placeholder text for password textbox
    private void textBox2_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!textBox2.Focused && textBox2.Text.Trim() == String.Empty)
            textBox2.Text = "Password: ";
    }

//Resets the placeholder text for password textbox
    private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!textBox1.Focused && textBox1.Text.Trim() == String.Empty)
            textBox1.Text = "Name: ";
    }
```

**TextBox.Focus()** is a method which make textbox an active control of the form. It also sets **TextBox.Focused** property to true.

Comment: It did not work with if-not-equal conditional but it worked with if-equal conditional. I also added added this new conditional to the button, which prevented  from outputting the placeholder text into the label. Thank you :).

Comment: @Shahrayar Thanks so much for answering again. A tiny question, what does it mean to be the active control of the form. Also, Why is it that when I change the Focused property in the textBox1_leave conditional into the Focus() method, I can't change the focus to the second text box and the button outputs nothing to the label ?!

Comment: You can call `focus()` for `textbox2` in `textbox1` leave event. It will work.

Answer (score 1):

This does look like a homework question, so I won't *give* you the answer, but I will help you out with some suggestions.

1. You need to stop being lazy with Control names. We all do it. But it has to stop. Six months from now you won't remember what `label5` is.

   - I suggest you begin renaming the controls on your form. For example, change the Name textbox to nameTextBox, and change the Name button to nameButton, and change the Name label to nameLabel.
2. Breakpoints. Use them. When something doesn't work out as expected, set a breakpoint on the line where you are expecting something to happen. For example, if you write:

   - `nameLabel.Text = nameTextBox.Text;` then you should set a breakpoint on that line, Debug your app and step through, watching the output window for anything that doesn't look right.

Comment: First of all, This is NOT a homework question. Second, I have enough coding sense to know that these names are indeed annoying, but changing them now in the properties did not change the method names. So how do I change the names?

Comment: Change yhem also in the .cs file and the .designer.cs file but just be very careful when changing the designer source. And I apologise for the incorrect assumption about your question being homework.

Comment: @Mustafa Never take any advice negatively. Obviously he is guiding you for the future.

Comment: @Shaharyar Oh no I did not take it negatively at all. Even though I think that SO community is a little harsh with programming newbies, I did not think Aeron's answer was harsh at all. But I guess the wording did convey that though :).